# Why TF tranformations from odometry to robot_base in P3DX devide by 1000?

Tags: slam, navigation, p3dx, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do Gmapping on P3DX using Hokuyo sensor and using RosAria in controlling.

I have seen many suggestion on doing TF like following tutorial.

http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/Poineer_mapping

In this tutorial, the code that transform odometry is below.

tf::Transform txOdom(odomQ, tf::Point((double) pos.getX()/1000.0, (double) pos.getY()/1000.0, pos.getTh()));
tf.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(txOdom, ros::Time::now() ,"odom", "base_footprint"));

And the discussion below which one gave the code of tf from odometry to base divide by 1000 as well.

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Pioneer3-td1265101.html

They all divided by 1000 in position from odometry. Why?

The problem I have when I divided by 1000 is gmapping seems to receive only first scan and do nothing else and wait for something. I guess Gmapping think the robot doesn't move. So, I tried to delete 1000 out and now Gmapping accept more data and make a map. I am not sure that I do it right or not in deleting 1000 out.

Could anyone explain the meaning of this? I would be very appreciated.
like what is the unit from aria and RosAria and what is the unit gmapping want to receive?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12022/why-tf-tranformations-from-odometry-to-robot_base-in-p3dx-devide-by-1000?/) by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-11-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect whatever node published the /odom transform is (mistakenly) doing it in millimeters instead of the [ROS standard](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#base-units), which is meters. Perhaps the Pioneer provides them in millimeters and the publishing node is not correcting it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on 2011-11-22**:
Thank you for guiding! I looked into Aria, they use millimeters as their base unit. RosAria also already changed the unit to meters. Therefore, I think there is no need to divide by 1000 anymore. If I am right, other people are transforming wrong data to gmapping.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-18**:
I also faced same problem.  Is it correct to remove division by 1000? Yes, map is generated after correction. This link http://www.ist.tugraz.at/robotics/bin/view/Main/Ros_first_steps shall also get updated!